# MySQL Find Peak Values Where Previous Value Is Lower?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, window-functions

I have an integer field and a datetime field.  Is there a query that could find all peak values or where there is a transition from low to high?  I don't think I can simply use `GROUP BY`  because the datetime values are too inconsistent.  The 'peaks' can happen at anytime (within the minute, hour, day, month etc.).

[image]

For example I need all values circled in red from the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want data points whose value is greater than the "following" value. You can use `lead()`. Assuming that your table has columns `date` and `value`, you would do:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, lead(value) over(order by date) lead_value
    from mytable t
) t
where value > lead_value
```